# Как сделать рекурсию чисел Фибоначи? Не могу понять, так как выводить последовательно

Tags: java, потоки-данных, scanner

Метод run () переопределить таким образом, чтобы числа Фибоначчи вводились в
обратном порядке. То есть сначала ввели через Scanner сколько мы хотим видеть цифр
Фибоначчи, затем с задержкой в 1 секунду вывести их от последнего к первому значения используя поток.

```
@Override         
public void run() {

System.out.println("****** Thread " + name + " started his work! ******");

    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int n;
    int fib_number;
    System.out.println("****** Enter a count of Fibonachi number which u want display: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
         fib_number = a + b;
         a = b;
         b = fib_number;
         System.out.println(fib_number + " ");
         try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("****** Thread " + name + " finished his work ******");
```

Проблема в том, что не могу понять как сделать рекурсию с числами Фибоначи, а не последовательный вывод.

Comment: Код писать пробовали? Покажите.

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы решение за вас написали?

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Есть [типовой пример рекурсии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/39232/190934):

```
int fib(int i) {
    if (i == 1) return 1;
    if (i == 2) return 1;
    return fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2);
}
```

Это алгоритм с экспоненциальной сложностью, и так нигде, кроме главы "рекурсия" в учебниках, не делают.

Если очень настаивают на рекурсии, можно написать так:

```
int fib( int n ) {
    return fibR( n, 0, 1 );
}

int fibR( int n, int a/*=0*/, int b/*=1*/ ) {
    if ( n == 0 ) return a;
    return fibR( n-1, b, a+b );
}
```

Это хвостовая рекурсия (рекурсивный вызов является последней операцией), и в некоторых языках программирования (например в Scala), компилятор оптимизировал бы код в цикл. В Java программа все равно вылетит с переполнением стека (`java.lang.StackOverflowError`), но алгоритм хотя бы имеет линейную сложность.