# java - Почему рекурсия так плоха?

Tags: java, рекурсия

Интересно. Почему рекурсия это плохо? Ведь это тот же самый цикл, даже более того, с возможностью передачи параметров. Такой "цикл" можно остановить `return`-ом. Да и бывает, что без неё никак (числа Фибоначчи).

**Почему в реальных проектах избегают её использование?**

Comment: простите, "без неё никак" - это без рекурсии для вычисления числ Фибоначи?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39229/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8 первый ответ

Comment: Ну это просто пример, скорее всего есть ещё другие "безэтогоникак"

Comment: а вы точно полностью прочитали ответ? "единственный способ **плохо** написать"

Comment: Прочитал но видимо не понял

Comment: Суть не в этом :)

Comment: Последовательность Фибоначчи прекрасно вычисляется и без рекурсии.

Comment: Ну знаете, нет ничего в мире, что можно однозначно охарактеризовать как "плохо" или "хорошо", так что вопрос изначально некорректен. В нужном месте, с прямыми руками...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ни одно из средств языка не может быть плохим или хорошим по определению.

Рекурсия даёт возможность программисту яснее выражать свои мысли всем (и в первую очередь компилятору), но цена этого - *понимание* происходящего. Нужно понимать что такое *стек* как он устроен, что кладётся в стек при вызове. Нужно иметь чуть более развитое воображение чтобы понимать когда рекурсия остановится и что будет с ней при вызовах. Нужно понимать почему глобальные переменные нужно менять осторожно и, одновременно, почему в функции должно быть как можно меньше переменных (вплоть до переиспользования).

Однако **любой** рекурсивный алгоритм может быть записан без рекурсии. (Обычно используя динамически расширяемый массив)

Основные проблемы конкретно рекурсии - неумение ей пользоваться. Многие  программисты, глядя на код из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/39232/182935 скажут что он правильный. На деле - там скрыта грубейшая ошибка - экспоненциальный а не линейный рост числа операций и памяти (ну если вы пишите не на функциональном ЯП).

Так же из классики рекурсии - неумение правильно задавать стек с помощью ключей компиляции (как часто вы в Java например собирали из командной строки или может вы помните как запустить поток с большим стеком).

Поэтому резюме (извините за грубость), если вы задаёте этот вопрос, тогда **не используйте** рекурсию, если вы осознаете что делаете - тогда это очень удобный инструмент повышающий читабельность кода в ряде задач и дающий поработать компилятору а не вам в смысле оптимизаций.

Comment: мне теперь захотелось узнать что за грубейшая ошибка в ответе в ссылке :D

Comment: Предположу, что, при передаче в параметр числа меньше 1, рекурсия никогда не закончится.

Comment: @КириллМалышев не самое страшное, то просто баг. А вот если число 30 передать =)

Comment: Великолепный ответ, спасибо :)

Comment: `экспоненциальный а не линейный рост` - почему линейный? Фибоначчи прекрасно вычисляются за `O(log(n))`

Answer (score 5):

Рекурсия не плоха. Просто она требует внимательного отношения к стеку. Так как он с каждым шагом прирастает, что часто приводит к переполнению.

И в принципе ее можно заменить на итерацию (цикл). Что обычно и советуют делать в языках, где нет [Хвостовой рекурсии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Например, в scala можно явно указать, что должна быть использованная **Хвостовая рекурсия** при помощи аннотации `@tailrec`, тогда вызов (call) будет заменен на переход (go to).

Comment: Ааааааа, вот оно что. Стек же хранит в себе вызовы методов. А как в рекурсии стек себя ведет? Он же должен передавать управление по завершению метода тому кто его вызвал. Что происходит со стеком в этот момент?

Comment: Для Java рекурсия - это просто вызов метода. Что происходит при вызове метода? Грубо говоря весь контекст метода сохраняется в стек.

Comment: Нет нет я про то что когда метод от работает то управление переходит тому кто его вызвал, тоесть тому же методу. И в итоге стек их не "убивает"?

Comment: это и называется контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильное использование рекурсии может привести к переполнению стека и к огромным вычислительным затратам. Однако, рекурсивный подход имеет существенный плюс в естественности алгоритма: при использовании аппарата математической индукции, можно легко протестировать правильность результата (помня об особенностях представления данных в памяти). Рекомендую помечать рекурсивные процедуры аннотацией @tailrec для проверки оптимизации функции.

Для оптимизации рекурсивного метода обычно прибегают к хвостовой рекурсии: передают в функцию дополнительный параметр, хранящий результаты предыдущего вычисления. Однако, в некоторых случаях этого недостаточно: например, в том же примере с числами Фибоначчи: тут нужно хранить список результатов. Для этого можно использовать ленивые коллекции, внутри или вне метода. Иногда возникают и более сложные задачи, когда, например, необходимо найти оптимальный список результатов. В этом случае можно использовать рекурсию с отсечением элементов.

Answer (score -1):

Ресурсозатратно. Пока программа углубляется в рекурсию, под локальные переменные выделяется место в памяти. А в цикле переменные просто обновляются.

Comment: Ещё хлеще :) Тоесть если в методе объявлены локальные переменные, штук 20, то если рекурсия вызовется раз 200, то их уже будет дветыщи

Comment: А там уже и до екзепшна недалеко.

Comment: `NotSouchOfMemoryException`

Comment: если у вас от 2 тысяч переменных закончилась память, то вы делаете что-то совсем не то...